# ngIf and classes in a picture html element

Tags: html, angular, image, conditional-statements

I'm starting on Angular and Typescript and I'm currently stumbling on a problem, so I'm looking for some guidance

I want to improve the speed of my site by displaying only images in webp format. However, some browsers don't seem to support it

That's why I use the `<picture>`tag to provide an alternative if the browser doesn't support the webp format contained in `<source>`. If it fails, it will then load the jpg image present in `<image>`

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
   <img src="image.png" alt="" title=""/>
</picture>
```

I would like to implement a class and an `*ngIf` condition to render the image only if a certain variable exists. But I don’t understand where I’m supposed to apply this? In the `<picture>` tag, in the `<source>` tag, or in the `<img>` tag?

Also, where should I place the alt and title attributes? In the `<img>` tag?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: It depends entirely on what you are trying to do. More detail is needed.

Comment: I use the picture tag to provide an alternative if the browser doesn't support the webp format contained in `<source>`. If it fails, it will load the jpg image present in `<image>`. ngif to render the image only if a certain variable exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though what you are trying to achieve is not clear but let me try to explain all the scenarios. Usually if the picture tag looks like that it means that the browser will try to load the webp image initially and if it fails it will load the image tag inside the picture.

So now lets discuss about applying ngIf condition. There are 3 possibilities and I will explain the situation

1. If applied on picture tag - It will render the picture depending on the condition. So if the condition is false it will not render any image in this case
2. If applied on source tag - It will add or remove the source tag from the picture based on the condition. The image will be rendered even if the condition is false because either it will load any of the other source tag if present or it will fallback to the img tag and render the image
3. If applied on img tag - It does not make any sense to apply ngIf on the image tag since that is a fall back image which will only be rendered if none of the above image can be rendered

As far as class or style property is concerned it can be applied on any of the tag. If applied on the picture tag that style is applicable to the container of the source tag. If you want to individually style each of the source tag you can do so by applying it specifically on the source tag. In most of the case applying style on the picture tag is what is needed.

Regarding alt and title attributes, title attribute can be placed on both source and img tag. But it makes sense to place the alt attribute in the img tag since that is the ultimate fall back image and if that can't be rendered the alt text will be displayed

Here is an [sample implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-11-playground-forked-pgjcz4) if you want to play with.

Please mark it as answer if it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an HTML `img` element.
2. Set the `src` attribute of the `img` element to the source of the image that needs to be displayed.
3. Add an `*ngIf` directive to the `img` element to check if the image should be displayed or not.
4. Create two CSS classes to style the `img` element, one for when the image is displayed and one for when it is hidden.
5. Add the class that corresponds to the `*ngIf` directive to the `img` element.

Here's the code:

```html
<img [src]="imageSource" *ngIf="showImage" [ngClass]="{ 'display-image': showImage, 'hide-image': !showImage }">
```

```css
.display-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.hide-image {
  display: none;
}
```

Note: In the code above, `imageSource` and `showImage` are variables that you will need to define in your component. Also, adjust the class names to match the desired styling.